# Keep one activity in the bottom of the backstack

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

I want to learn the proper way to manage the activity back stack with regards to my issue. Most of the time when a person uses my app, I want to keep an activity in the bottom of the stack, let's call this Activity A. This would be their "Home" activity. I have a navigation view which can take the user to a bunch of other activities, but I want to manage what displays when they tap back. I want Activity A to always be the last activity in the stack, so the stack can look like A -> B -> C-> D, and when the user is on Activity D and they want to go to Activity E, I want the stack to look like A -> E when they press it.

A possible solution I have found is by clearing all the activities in the current stack, launching Activity A, and sending an intent for Activity E in the intent I launch Activity A with, then that will just check it's intent extras and if it finds an intent in the extras it would just launch that intent. This results in the stack looking the way I want, Activity A -> Activity E. I just want to know if there is a better or simpler way.

I have tinkered with the activity properties in my manifest, but it seems like I can't do exactly what I would like to with those.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you want to keep activity A in the back stack so that whenever a user presses back, you want to show activity A on top. Lets say you go to B from A and then C from B. So whenever you go from any activity(other than A) to any other activity just call finish() from the calling activity, this will remove the stack entry of the corresponding activity, ensuring that only activity is there in the back stack.

Comment: This is a good approach, but it will not account for certain situations where I want the back-stack to be filled with a string of related activities, where I would want the user to be able to go back to the previous activity